# using Map to implement efficient searching process - java

Tags: java

I am creating a phone book API in Java. Every name in my phone book is mapped to a set of phone numbers & address. I want to build a search function which can search an entry in my phone book using a search parameter as a name or as the phone number itself.

My approach has been to add all my entries to a:

```
Map <String, PhoneNumber> book = new HashMap <String,PhoneNumber>();
book.put("Name1",new PhoneNumber(new Integer(12345),new Integer(123456));
book.get("Name1");
// PhoneNumber is my class which can have different types of phone numbers
```

I want to search by both the name which is the key and also by the value. I cannot do that using a `HashMap`. Is there a way to do it better to implement an efficient searching process?

Comment: Don't represent phone numbers as integers.  You cannot represent leading zeros or # with an integer.

Comment: Good catch @thorbjorn.  Further, phone numbers aren't really numbers - it makes no sense to do math on a phone number. Therefore, it isn't a number even if it looks like one.  So we what see here could be a generic 'lookup' class, and a 'phone book' subclass that applies a 'the key must be a numeric string' rule.

Comment: @Tony, the "key must be numeric string" does not allow for #'s.

Comment: By '#' do you mean 'the key must be comprised of characters between 0 and 9 inclusive'?  If so, I think we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a Map for your phone book.  It's too limited. Instead create a PhoneBook class.  Within that class have 2 Maps, one for the by-name searching and one for the by-number searching.  Create an add() routine that adds Info to both maps.

```
public class PhoneBook {
   private Map<String,Info> byNumber;
   private Map<String,Info> byName;
}
```

Where "Info" is a class that tells you everything about the person.

Comment: The above assumes names are unique.  That's unrealistic of course.  If they aren't, you'd likely have:  `private Map<String,List<Info>> byName;` so you get a list of all people with that name.